# WKWebView throwing HTTP ERROR 401- Authorization Failed in Cocoa(Mac application) in swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, wkwebview, http-status-code-401

I am opening webApplication in Mac app, to open webApplication I am using webView.load method to display content in webView. Most of the time able to load content but sometime throwing Authorization Failed error. It’s an intermittent issue.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse,
                 decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {

        if let response = navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("Response: \(response)")
            
            if response.statusCode == 401 {
```

WebApplication using AppleConnect singleSignOn.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        if let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust {
            completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.performDefaultHandling, URLCredential(trust: serverTrust))
            //completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.performDefaultHandling, nil)
            
        }
    }
```

This error getting only in Big Sur OS, not in Catalina and It’s an intermittent issue not continuous. Anyone faced this issue before?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To resolve Authorization failed error, I have added non-persistent code

```
let webViewConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: webViewConfig)
```

> /** @abstract Returns a new non-persistent data store.
> @discussion If a WKWebView is associated with a non-persistent data store, no data will
> be written to the file system. This is useful for implementing "private browsing" in a web view.
> */